I want to change the appearance of a URL on a subdomain
I have a website hosted on IIS.
parent.com

I have a link that points to
sub.parent.com:1234/folder/page

I want to change it's appearance to look like
parent.com/different/name

How can I accomplish this?


What's the output of curl parent.com/different/name in PowerShell console? You have to edit and add that to the question. 2) If the output shows no error, then install IIS URL Rewrite module and add a rewrite rule to redirect from the old URL to the new one. If you are not familiar with rule authoring, learn from the tutorial or a modern AI, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module

